# class clash on button style element

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a Button that is styled like this:

```
<a class="mini pink button">Arrange Viewing</a>
```

And we also use scroll to, which if it was applied to a href link would look like this.

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">Arrange Viewing</a>
```

The issue I have is I want the mini pink button to on click scroll to content, but I cannot have 2 classes on same object.

css for the button is:

```
    a.button {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "proxima-nova-1","proxima-nova-2",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 9px 34px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mini.button {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
.pink, .pinkaswell {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EC008C;
}
```

js for the scroll to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

FIDDLE here http://jsfiddle.net/VtxnK/

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly. Why can't you "have 2 classes on same object"? You can't expect us to disect your code in order to find the issue we think you are describing...

Comment: How can you have 2 classes on one object ? I thought each element was limited to one ID and one CLASS.

Comment: Technically, an HTML element (lets call it that rather than an object -- an object is a very general programming term) can only have one ID, but an unlimited number of classes.

Comment: Ahh okies gottya Max , thanks. I wasnt aware of that. Cheers for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two classes on an object, you just can't have two class attributes. Just add the class name on to the end of the other classes.

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="mini pink button anchorLink">
    Arrange Viewing
</a>
```

Or, since you have an id, you can access it by the id...

```
$( "#anchor1" ).anchorAnimate();
```

Comment: could you implement that on this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/VtxnK/ sorry jsfiddle just crapped itself for me